# how i can use id mapping of 1st api response while using ngFor for 2nd api response

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and having two apis as per below response

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "manager"
    }
}
```

```
{
    {
        "type": 1,
        "employee - name": "rob"
    },
    {
        "type": 2,
        "employee - name": "bob"
    }
}
```

expected output

```
employee-name : employee-type
rob : developer
bob : manager
```

How i can use “id” mapping of 1st api response while using ngFor for 2nd api response for “type”

Answer (score 0):

first of all i assume your data to be an array instead of object that you posted here

```
this.types=[ {“id”:1,”name”:”developer”},
{“id”:2,”name”:”manager”}]
```

and

```
this.emps=[{“type”:1,”employee-name”:”rob”},
{“type”:2,”employee-name”:”bob”}]
```

then create method to get type

```
 getType(typeid){
     var type=this.types.find(t=>t.id == typeid);
 if(type){
return type.name
}
}
```

then in your html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Type</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of emps">
<td>{{item['employee-name']}}</td>
<td>{{getType(item.type)}} 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prsmqk)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that types and employees are actually arrays, secondly I'd use a map function to build new object that already has everything:

```js
const types = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "manager"
    }
]

const employees = [
    {
        "type": 1,
        "employee - name": "rob"
    },
    {
        "type": 2,
        "employee - name": "bob"
    }
];


const employeesWithTypeNames = employees.map(employee => ({
    name: employee['employee - name'],
    type: types.find(t => t.id === employee.type).name
}));
```

Then it's a matter of iterating through this object using `*ngFor`:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Type</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeesWithTypeNames">
        <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.type }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously this isn't full blown solution, but this will do the trick.